# Google Analytics 4 Permission Problem (User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.)

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

When we used the previous version of GA, everything works fine, but when we upgrade to GA4 we have a problem like this:

```
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "errors": [ { "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }
```

It's totally unclear why this unexpected error occurs, is there any solution for this?
The publisher gave us viewer permissions.

Comment: Can you post your requests? or code?

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4) which does not work with GA4 properties. Accessing GA4 properties with this API will give you a 403 error.

You need to use [GA4 Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) for GA4 properties, and may need to upgrade your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you do a google search for GA4 reporting you can easily end up on one of the quick start guides for Reporting API v4. I ended up on the [python one](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py)

The main page of the guide says its not for GA4 but the language specific ones don't mention it.

So you need to find the [GA4 Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) which doesn't seem to rank as high in google searches.